# Couldn't reduce the looping variable inside the "for" loop in R

Tags: r

I have a for loop to do a matrix manipulation in R. For some checks are true i need to come to the same row again., means `i` need to be reduced by 1.

```
for(i in 1:10)
{
    if(some chk)
    {
    i=i-1
    }
}
```

Actually `i` is not reduced for me. For an example in 5th row i'm reducing the i to 4, so again it should come as 5, but it is coming as 6.
Please advice.

My intention is:
Checking the first column values of a matrix, if I find any duplicate value, I take the second column value and append with the first row's second column and remove the duplicate row. So, when I'm removing a row I do not need increase the i in while loop. (This is just a map reduce method, append values of same key)

Comment: You should edit your question with the contents of your comment below so that we can tell what your actual desired output is.

Answer (score 3):

Variables in R `for` loops are read-only, you cannot modify them. What you have written would be solved completely differently in normal R code – the exact solution depending on the actual problem, there isn’t a generic, direct replacement (except by replacing the whole thing with a `while` loop but this is both ugly and probably unnecessary).

To illustrate this, consider these two typical examples.

1. Assume you want to filter all duplicated elements from a list. Instead of looping over the list and copying all duplicated elements, you can use the [`duplicated`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/duplicated.html) function which tells you, for each element, whether it’s a duplicate.

   Secondly, you use [standard R subsetting syntax](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) to select just those elements which are not a duplicate:

   ```
   x = x[! duplicated(x)]
   ```

   (This example works on a one-dimensional vector or list, but it can be generalised to more dimensions.)
2. For a more complex case, let’s say that you have a vector of numbers and, for every *even* number in the vector, you want to double the preceding number (this is highly artificial but in signal processing you might face similar problems). In other words:

   ```
   input = c(1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 1, 8)
   output = ???
   output
   # [1]  1  6  2 10  6  7  2  8
   ```

   … we want to fill in `???`. In the first step, we check which numbers are even:

   ```
   even = input %% 2 == 0
   # [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
   ```

   Next, we shift the result down – because we want to know whether the *next* number is even – by removing the first element, and appending a dummy element (`FALSE`) at the end.

   ```
   even = c(even[-1], FALSE)
   # [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
   ```

   And now we can multiply just these inputs by two:

   ```
   output = input
   output[even] = output[even] * 2
   ```

   There, done.

Comment: Since i need a simple matrix traversal "while" is working fine.

Comment: @Nadaraj I am certain that you are doing it wrong. If you want to traverse a matrix, you don’t want to manually manipulate indices, and you don’t want either `for` or `while`. You want something like `apply`.

Comment: What I'm doing is, checking the first column values, if I found any duplicate value, i'm removing the entire row. So, when I'm removing a row I do not need increase the `i` in `while` loop. If you have any other good methods please share with me.

Comment: @Nadaraj `yourmatrix[!duplicated(yourmatrix[, 1],]` There are always very good odds that a `for` or `while` loop is the least efficient method in R.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, could you add an example with `apply` family function to emphasize power of vectorization in R

Comment: @Osssan I’ve added two examples, but neither actually uses `apply`. I’m hard-pressed to think of a case where you would jump between indices as OP does, and could actually use `apply`. You could rewrite my second example using `mapply`, but there’s actually no need for that.